# Writing and formatting the content of a text file to a PDF file

Tags: python, file, pyfpdf

I want to create PDF file and write text that I read from file. The text in the file looks like:

```
Hello World. This is test text.
ASDFASDFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Hello World. This is test text.
ASDFASDFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Hello World. This is test text.
ASDFASDFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

I created PDF with FPDF library. The code:

```
pdf = FPDF()

pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 14)
pdf.text(0, 0 , text)

pdf.output(fileNameBase + ".pdf", "F")
```

The issue is the text is rendered in one line. So the text is not fully shown. I want to write text with the same format in text file. How can I create PDF file with the same format in the text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [multi_cell()](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/multi_cell/index.html) method instead of `text()` method.
`multi_cell` or `cell` are directly recommended by the [text()](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/text/index.html) method documentation:

> From **text()** method documentation:
> text() method prints a character string. The origin is on the left of the first character, on the baseline. This method allows placing a string precisely on the page, **but it is usually easier to use cell, multi_cell or write**, which are the standard methods to print text.

To test your program I have created a text file called `file.txt` which contains your example text:

```
Hello World. This is test text.
ASDFASDFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Hello World. This is test text.
ASDFASDFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Hello World. This is test text.
ASDFASDFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Changing your code to use `multi_cell()` and read the text message to write to the PDF file, from the text file `file.txt`, your program becomes:

```py
from fpdf import FPDF
import webbrowser

fileNameBase = "question_so"

'''+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Reads and returns the text contained into the file.txt 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'''
def get_file_content():
    text = ""
    with open('file.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            text += line
    return text

def main():

    pdf = FPDF()

    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 14)
    # I have commented your call to text() method
    #pdf.text(0, 0 , text)
    # read the content of the file
    text = get_file_content()
    pdf.multi_cell(w=210, h=6, txt=text, border=0, align='L', fill=False)

    pdf.output(fileNameBase + ".pdf", "F")
    webbrowser.open_new('question_so.pdf')

main()
```

By the execution of the function `main()` I get a PDF file called `question_so.pdf` with the content showed by the following image:

[image: the PDF content]

Comment: If you are not bound to FPDF, then PyMuPDF (I am one of the maintainers) offers a simple solution: simply do `page.insert_text(start_point, text)`. Line breaks inside the text are automatically honored. In addition, `text` may also be a list of strings, which leads to the same result.

Comment: @Jorj McKie thank you. I'll try to learn it when it will be possible.